# Binary Search Tree-> Inorder traversal method not printing the value inserted

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search, inorder

This is the code for the Binary Search Tree Deletion,when I try to insert the elements in the tree and print, the values appearing are zeros. I tried using debugging techniques, the error appears to come from the `"void insert()"`method, as the `root.key` element does not print the user inserted element from the `inorderRec() method`. I am still learning tree DS. thanks in advance guys.

Node class:

```
class Node { 

    int key; //elements
    Node left, right; //positions

    //constructor
    public Node(int item) {
        item = key;
        left = right = null;
    }
}
```

BST CLASS:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package binarysearchdeletion;

/**
 *
 * @author Srt
 */
 class BinarySearchDeletion {

     Node root;

    public BinarySearchDeletion() {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        BinarySearchDeletion tree = new BinarySearchDeletion();


        System.out.println("print the statement");
         tree.insert(50);
         tree.inorder();

    }



    //delete method,, to delete keys
    void delete(int key) {
        root = deleteRec(root, key);
    }
    //delete recursion method

    Node deleteRec(Node root, int key) {
        //if tree is empty return the root
        if (root == null) {
            return root;
        }

        //deleteing the leaf node based on the input
        if (key < root.key) {
            root.left = deleteRec(root.left, key);
        } else if (key > root.key) {
            root.right = deleteRec(root.right, key);
        } //deleting node when the parent has only one child.
         else {
            // node with only one child or no child
            if (root.left == null) {
                return root.right;
            } else if (root.right == null) {
                return root.left;
            }

            //deleting node when the parent has two children(inorder traversal-> the samllest in the right sub-tree)   
            root.key = minValue(root.right);
            //delete the successor when it is placed and copied to the position of the deleted parent

            root.right = deleteRec(root.right, root.key);
        }
        return root;
    }

    //method for calling the samllest element greater than the input node to be deleted
    int minValue(Node root) {
        int minval = root.key;
        while (root.left != null) {
            minval = root.left.key;
            root = root.left;
        }
        return minval;
    }

    //calls the insert recursion method
    void insert(int key) {
       // System.out.println(key);
        root = insertRec(root, key); //the problem is here
      // System.out.println("insert method "+root.key);
    }
//inserting recursion method inserting the elements based on the control structure conditions

    Node insertRec(Node root, int key) {

        //if tree empty
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(key);
            return root;
        }
//inserting based on the BST properties and recur down
        if (key < root.key) {
            root.left = insertRec(root.left, key);
        } else if (key > root.key) {
            root.right = insertRec(root.right, key);
        }

        return root;
    }

    //calls inorder recursion method


    void inorderRec(Node root) {
         if (root != null) {
            inorderRec(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.key + " ");
            inorderRec(root.right);
        }
    }
    void inorder() {
      //  System.out.println(key);
        inorderRec(root);
    }

}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT WHICH I AM GETTING:

```
print the statement
0
```

EXPECTED Output:

```
print the statement
50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very small problem with your Node class which is causing your program to give the wrong answer. Your constructor for Node looks like this:

```
public Node(int item) {
    item = key; // mistake here
    left = right = null;
}
```

The problem is that you are setting the value of item to the value of key (which is initialized to 0) instead of key to item. You should change it to:

```
public Node(int item) {
    key = item; //fixed
    left = right = null;
}
```